# how to resolve 'something went wrong' while working with flutter_stripe?

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, flutter-dependencies

I am continuosly getting "something went wrong" from stripe server and when I go to the stripe dashboard it indicates status = incomplete with hint "The customer has not entered their payment method.".  I'm not sure what or how to solve this but I would really need some help on this one. Also I included with the screenshot of the problem.

```
 final client = http.Client();
  Logger logger = Logger();
  static Map<String, String> headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ${dotenv.env['STRIPE_SECRET']}',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  };

  void _init() {
    Stripe.publishableKey = dotenv.env['STRIPE_PUB_KEY'] ?? '';
  }

 
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> createCustomer({required String paymentId}) async {
    final String url = 'https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers';
    var response = await client.post(
      Uri.parse(url),
      headers: headers,
      body: {
        "name":"yash hikare",
        "email":"yash1@gmail.com",
        "payment_method": paymentId,
        'description':
            '${dashboardController.profileDetails.value.firstName} ${dashboardController.profileDetails.value.lastName}'
      },
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return json.decode(response.body);
    } else {
      print(json.decode(response.body));
      throw 'Failed to register as a customer.';
    }
  }

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> _createPaymentIntents() async {
    final String url = 'https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents';

    Map<String, dynamic> body = {'amount': '2000', 'currency': 'usd'};

    var response =
        await client.post(Uri.parse(url), headers: headers, body: body);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      logger.d(response.body);
      return json.decode(response.body);
    } else {
      print(json.decode(response.body));
      throw 'Failed to create PaymentIntents.';
    }
  }

  Future<void> _createCreditCard(
      String customerId, String paymentIntentClientSecret) async {
    await Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
        paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
      style: ThemeMode.dark,
      merchantDisplayName: 'Iloma',
      customerId: customerId,
      paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentIntentClientSecret,
    ));
    await displayPaymentSheet();
    // await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet();
  }

  displayPaymentSheet() async {
    try {
      await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet().then((value) {
        // Stripe.instance.confirmPaymentSheetPayment();
        showToast(message: "Payment successful");
        // paymentIntent = null;
      }
      ).onError((error, stackTrace) {
        showToast(message: "Payment flow has been cancelled");
      });
    } on StripeException {
      showToast(message: "Payment flow has been cancelled");
    } catch (e) {
      showToast(message: "Error $e");
    }
  }

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> _createPaymentMethod(
      {required String number,
      required String expMonth,
      required String token,
      required String expYear,
      required String cvc}) async {
    final String url = 'https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_methods';
    var response = await client.post(
      Uri.parse(url),
      headers: headers,
      body: {
        'type': 'card',
        'card[token]': '$token',
        // 'type': 'card',
        // 'card[number]': '$number',
        // 'card[exp_month]': '$expMonth',
        // 'card[exp_year]': '$expYear',
        // 'card[cvc]': '$cvc',
      },
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      logger.d(response.body);
      return json.decode(response.body);
    } else {
      print(json.decode(response.body));
      throw 'Failed to create PaymentMethod.';
    }
  }

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> _attachPaymentMethod(
      String paymentMethodId, String customerId) async {
    final String url =
        'https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_methods/$paymentMethodId/attach';
    var response = await client.post(
      Uri.parse(url),
      headers: headers,
      body: {
        'customer': customerId,
      },
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return json.decode(response.body);
    } else {
      logger.d(json.decode(response.body));
      throw 'Failed to attach PaymentMethod.';
    }
  }
```

Comment: Not too familiar with Flutter Stripe, but I do notice that you're making API calls client-side with your secret key. You should never do that, as that exposes your secret key. You should make those requests on a server and call the server's endpoint client-side.